# Sphinx in-line math equation alignment

Tags: formatting, tools, sphinx

As suggested by the answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/best-authoring-environment-meta-language-for-multi-targeting-output/23699#23699), I am using the Sphinx tool in order to multi-target PDF and HTML output. For HTML, I'm using the pngmath extension.

The vertical alignment of inline math in the HTML output is very bothersome. The math equations are positioned below where they should and this causes the entire rendered page to look bad because none of the equations are lined-up properly.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my question about exactly that](http://www.mail-archive.com/sphinx-dev@googlegroups.com/msg03495.html), in short the solution is to add to `conf.py`:

```
pngmath_latex_preamble=r'\usepackage[active]{preview}' # + other custom stuff for inline math, such as non-default math fonts etc.
pngmath_use_preview=True
```

This "feature" is explained [in sphinx docs](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html#confval-pngmath_use_preview).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Why anyone would want that "feature" escapse me.

Comment: They say it is because the `preview` package does not come installed with LaTeX in all distributions. Personally I think it would be better to force people install it, because it really looks horrible without it.

Comment: Sorry, Could you confirm where in the conf.py you need to add those lines?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/woodem/woo-doc/blob/f07c29d21e7ff0216f59d18771d6a5fdaecce91b/sphinx2/source/conf.py#L171) but I have not generated pngmath for ages (but the conf.py did not change for ages, either ;) ). In short, it does not matter where you put it really Important is that the variable is defined after conf.py is processed.